# Failed starting jasperserver: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, jasperserver

I'm trying to start for the very first time Jasperserver and as you probably thinking at this point it didn't end up very well.

**What I've done:**

1. Install Tomcat v7.0.32
2. Install Jasperreport v7.1.0

**Note:**

- When i was installing jasperreport server i've choose to use an
  external source. I've linked that to the tomcat.
- During jasperreport installation i've also installed postgreSQL.
- When i was installing the tomcat i've choose to use a different port 8000 -> 
  9000.
- I'm using Windows 10

**What I'm doing:**

- Staring the tomcat manager (as administrator).
- Opening in a browser localhost:9000/manager/html

**The Error:**

- If i try to access to localhost:9000/jasperserver:

[image: Jasperserver 404]

- So I've checked the log file and there is an error in more than one file:

*tomcat7-stdout.2018-06-14:*

```
    2018-06-14 10:16:46 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000074b5c75a, pid=4528, tid=11980
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_80-b15) (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.80-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x1cc75a]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\hs_err_pid4528.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
virtualDataSourceQueryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teiidVirtualQueryService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-virtual-data-source-query-service.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/infinispan/manager/EmbeddedCacheManager : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManager)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:638)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1105)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1664)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'virtualDataSourceHandler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-virtual-data-source.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'teiidVirtualQueryService' while setting bean property 'virtualDataSourceQueryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teiidVirtualQueryService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-virtual-data-source-query-service.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/infinispan/manager/EmbeddedCacheManager : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManager)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teiidVirtualQueryService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-virtual-data-source-query-service.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/infinispan/manager/EmbeddedCacheManager : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManager)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/infinispan/manager/EmbeddedCacheManager : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManager)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2908)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.common.virtualdatasourcequery.impl.TeiidVirtualDataSourceQueryServiceImpl.startServer(TeiidVirtualDataSourceQueryServiceImpl.java:525)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.common.virtualdatasourcequery.impl.TeiidVirtualDataSourceQueryServiceImpl.init(TeiidVirtualDataSourceQueryServiceImpl.java:519)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.common.virtualdatasourcequery.impl.TeiidVirtualDataSourceQueryServiceImpl.afterPropertiesSet(TeiidVirtualDataSourceQueryServiceImpl.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511)
    ... 45 more
2018-06-14 10:18:25,475 ERROR JNDIResourceProvider,localhost-startStop-1:75 - error closing context
javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: Context is read only
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.checkWritable(NamingContext.java:962)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.close(NamingContext.java:762)
    at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.JNDIResourceProvider.close(JNDIResourceProvider.java:72)
    at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.CompositeResourceProvider.close(CompositeResourceProvider.java:56)
    at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.ResourcesFactory.initialize(ResourcesFactory.java:163)
    at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.ResourcesFactory.<init>(ResourcesFactory.java:92)
    at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.ResourcesFactory.<clinit>(ResourcesFactory.java:89)
    at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.ResourcesFactoryContextListener.contextInitialized(ResourcesFactoryContextListener.java:23)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1105)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1664)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

*localhost.2018-06-14:*

```
INFORMAZIONI: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
giu 14, 2018 10:18:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customJDBCReportDataSourceServiceFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'virtualDataSourceHandler' while setting bean property 'virtualDataSourceHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'virtualDataSourceHandler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-virtual-data-source.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'teiidVirtualQueryService' while setting bean property 'virtualDataSourceQueryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teiidVirtualQueryService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-virtual-data-source-query-service.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/infinispan/manager/EmbeddedCacheManager : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManager)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:638)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1105)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1664)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'virtualDataSourceHandler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-virtual-data-source.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'teiidVirtualQueryService' while setting bean property 'virtualDataSourceQueryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teiidVirtualQueryService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-virtual-data-source-query-service.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/infinispan/manager/EmbeddedCacheManager : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManager)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teiidVirtualQueryService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-virtual-data-source-query-service.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/infinispan/manager/EmbeddedCacheManager : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManager)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/infinispan/manager/EmbeddedCacheManager : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManager)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2908)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.common.virtualdatasourcequery.impl.TeiidVirtualDataSourceQueryServiceImpl.startServer(TeiidVirtualDataSourceQueryServiceImpl.java:525)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.common.virtualdatasourcequery.impl.TeiidVirtualDataSourceQueryServiceImpl.init(TeiidVirtualDataSourceQueryServiceImpl.java:519)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.common.virtualdatasourcequery.impl.TeiidVirtualDataSourceQueryServiceImpl.afterPropertiesSet(TeiidVirtualDataSourceQueryServiceImpl.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511)
    ... 45 more
```

**Conclusion:**

I've really no idea what to do! I've tryed to google it but everything is old and not relevant for the error i got. Hopefully you can help me!

**Edit 18/06/2018**

[image: Java version]

**Edit 22/06/2018**

[image: Java -version on cmd]

Comment: what is your JRE_HOME and CLASSPATH ?

Comment: 52 = java 1.8 Somehow, somewhere java 1.8 is being used. Please post the output when you run `java -version` and `javac -version` on CMD

Comment: @Fabulous I've added an image with the command run, if you are so kind to tell me where i need to go for JRE_HOME and CLASSPATH then ill post

Comment: I think what is happening is that you have java 1.8 in your system, but tomcat expects java 1.7 and cannot find it. That is why you get `UnsupportedClassVersion` with `major minor` error. Just to be sure, search for "environment variables" and post the value of "PATH" and "JRE_HOME" vars

Comment: Perhaps you need to point tomcat to Java 1.7. Did you try configuring build path of the project? I am talking from an eclipse perspective

Comment: @Fabulous My PATH is pointing to "\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\" and i don't have a JRE_HOME variable

Comment: @Fabulous Sorry if i sound stupid but is the first time i use that, by the way i'm not trying to open jasperserver from an eclipe prospective, right now. As i said in the post  i've installed the tomcat in my pc and i'm using a browser interface

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173607/discussion-between-fabulous-and-g-ciardini).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that even though you have JRE 1.7 installed to which Tomcat is pointing to, your system has JRE 1.8 which is actually running. Also, you do not have JDK installed. It is needed to compile Java classes.

Try the following:

1. Download JDK 1.8 for Windows from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html. You have to accept the license agreement first.
2. Run the installer. There should not be many options for you to configure, except the install path. Remember this path for later use
3. When the installer has finished, search for "environment variables". When there, look for `PATH` variable and `CLASSPATH`. If they are not there, you can create them by adding a new variable.
4. Edit `PATH` variable, add ";path\in\step\2\bin\". In case you do not remember, it is usually `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\`. The `PATH` variable gives the location of executables like javac, java etc...
5. Create `JAVA_HOME` variable and set it to "path/to/jdk". It should be like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25`
6. Create `JRE_HOME` variable and set it to "path/to/jre". It should look like `JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\jre`
7. Create `CATALINA_HOME` variable and set it to the path of the directory into which you have installed Tomcat 4.1. It should look `C:\Program Files\Apache\tomcat\bin\startup`
8. Create `CLASSPATH` variable and set it to "path\common\lib\servlet-api.jar". It should look something like `C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.14\lib\servlet-api.jar`.
9. Check if these have been set properly by echoing them on cmd. Simply type `%PATH%`, `%JAVA_HOME%`,`%JRE_HOME%` etc. into cmd. They should produce the same values as that set in earlier steps.
10. Finally, check if Java has been installed correctly by typing in `javac` and hitting enter on cmd. If you get an output like "Usage: javac ....", then it has been installed correctly.
11. Run your project.

`PATH` is an environment variable used by the operating system (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux) where it will look for native executable programs to run. `JAVA_HOME`,`JRE_HOME` are not used by Java itself. Apache Tomcat expects one of these environment variables to be set to the installation directory of the JDK or JRE. `CLASSPATH` is used by 3rd party apps like tomcat to inject whatever is set in `CLASSPATH` to every java application you make.`CATALINA_HOME` points to the installation of tomcat, which may be needed at startup. 
.

It's possible that the error is coming as you have not set the variables

Comment: Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 means a Java version mismatch, switch to Java 8

Comment: Doesn't work! Check the update i've add you my java version

Comment: Agree about the JDK version - note this in the stdout: `JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_80-b15) (build 1.7.0_80-b15)`

Comment: Still didn't fix my problem